# Inline-embedded image in Internet Shortcut .URL file?

Tags: url

I have tried to inline-embedding an image inside an Internet Shortcut .URL file:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-URL
<img src="data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABGdBTUEAALGP
C/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YGARc5KB0XV+IA
AAAddEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIFRoZSBHSU1Q72QlbgAAAF1J
REFUGNO9zL0NglAAxPEfdLTs4BZM4DIO4C7OwQg2JoQ9LE1exdlYvBBeZ7jq
ch9//q1uH4TLzw4d6+ErXMMcXuHWxId3KOETnnXXV6MJpcq2MLaI97CER3N0
vr4MkhoXe0rZigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="red dot" />
```

The aim is to display the shortcut file as an image (in this case a red dot image) in Windows File Explorer.

Unfortunately, the above code example does not work in the intended way.

Is it generally possible at all to inline-embed an image inside an Internet Shortcut .URL file in a similar way?

Comment: I would also like to know if this is possible. Setting `IconFile=data:image/x-icon;base64,<content>` didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can't include an img-tag into an `.url` file. The file is structured like an `.ini` file in Windows.

However, it is possible to link an icon (`.ico`) file by specifying `IconFile`.

cf. https://superuser.com/questions/898669/what-makes-internet-shortcut-files-special

Comment: But the icon is an EXTERNAL file. I need to keep everything inside the .URL file. Isn't there a way to ENCODE the icon inside the .URL file?